# "test-netconnection" shoes false even if a port is open

Tags: netconnection

I have been using `test-netconnection -computername myserver -port 433` as a test to check if I can access a port on a server from a laptop.

if `TcpTestSucceeded` was `false` I took it that the server was not accessible on that port.

Yesterday I realised that this was not necessarily the case as `TcpTestSucceeded` would be `false`, even if the port was open, unless a website on the server was bound to that port.

Is there a command that can check if the port on the server is open, regardless of whether there is a website bound to it?

Thanks in advance.